# Stepping Down Logic Level of a Differential Signal

Tags: voltage-divider, differential, level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVbY0L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose I have a unipolar, differential 24V signal, and I want to step it down for use with a 5V differential receiver (such as RS-422), how can this be done?

Can I just use a voltage divider to step it down like above?

Comment: An encoder powered off a 24V supply won't be outputting a 24V signal over its RS-422, any more your computer's USB port is sending a 120V signal just because your computer is powered off the 120VAC from the wall. Your question also doesn't make sense either since your 422 receiver won't work properly if it doesn't receive the compliment. The RS-422 is referencing using A and A' as the reference voltage to determine the signal logic level, not ground which will not be present if you do not connect both.

Comment: I meant that if I was using a single ended encoder (without RS-422 receiver), I could just use an opto to step down the voltage.

Comment: What is the output current on the A and B lines?

Comment: You could use a resistive divider to step down each signal and feed it to two parallel wired oppositely comparators to produce X and X' to feed your 422 receiver. Or feed the resistive divider to a RS-422 transmitter.

Comment: Why would I need use comparators? Couldn't I just use the voltage divider on each output leg of the encoder and feed straight into the 422 receiver? I've now realised that the encoder in question does output TTL level voltage, so only asking out of curiosity/to further learning

Comment: @19172281 what model number is the encoder?

Comment: @19172281 Because of the complimentary signal. Were you just...not going to do anything with the A' and B' on the RS-422?

Comment: @DKNguyen, I was going to use a voltage divider on them too. And then feed everything into the 422 receiver. Surely then A, /A, B, /B are essentially the same except at a lower voltage.

Comment: @19172281 I'm confused. You said earlier that the encoder was single-ended. You can't produce A and A' by stepping the same source signal down by different ratios. Do you not understand what a differential signal is?

Comment: @DKNguyen, You said my question didn't make sense because I mentioned not using the A and B compliments. What I was trying to say was that if I was using a single ended encoder, and thus no compliments and RS-422 receiver, a simple opto on A and B would suffice to step down the voltage and feed straight into my processor.

The actual encoder in question IS RS-422, so I would think that a voltage divider on A, /A, B, /B and then feed into the 422 receiver would work.

Comment: @19172281 Oh. So you're not trying to wire a single-ended encoder to a RS-422 receiver. You're trying to wire a RS-422 encoder to single-ended inputs. Yes you can do that. I wouldn't recommend it though. One of the first things I did at my current job was to rectify something wired like that. It worked at least some of the time but suffered from numerous issues which I just swept through and fixed all of them without checking issue was related to which fix.

Comment: @DKNguyen, not quite. Really what I'm asking is how you would step down the voltage of a differential signal before inputting it into a differential line receiver. I can't think of any other way to do it other than using a voltage divider.

Comment: @19172281 This website has a schematic editor. You can "custom" components just by using the dotted block and text labels. Could you edit your post and draw a diagram of what you are trying to do? Or at least, what your question truly is?

Comment: @DKNguyen, simplified schematic added. Please ignore resistor values

Comment: @19172281 An "RS-422 encoder" already implies certain output voltage levels. Your question is regarding 24V differential outputs in general, right?

Comment: @DKNguyen, correct.

Comment: @19172281 I cleaned up your post. That should work. I would just watch for the typical issues such as too slow rise/fall time issues, noise, loading the inputs. You could potentially benefit from having filter capacitors across the differential line itself or the divider outputs, but the former is likely to affect rise/fall times quite a bit more for the same capacitance, but will load it less.

Comment: Slow rise/fall times was something I was concerned about. Would this be an issue with, say, a 24v 4096PPR encoder over 30 metres?

Comment: 19172281:  the voltage divider resistors will form an R-C low pass filter with the capacitance at the receiver inputs.  This capacitance will be from the receiver chip and any wires or cables on the input nodes.  You can estimate the slowing of the edges using tr=2.2 R*C, R=voltage divider resistors in parallel, C=total capacitance at the input node.